# Routes Not working correct in post man gives Post Not allowed

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am creating a web api using mvc and visual studio however I am comming across a problem. I am running this on the desktop version of post man by the way not the browser via local host.

The way I am calling the url is

http://localhost:12513/api/CustomerContracts/AddCustomer

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("AddCustomer/{description}/{customerRef}/{contractTypeId}/{startDate}/{EndDate}")]

public async Task AddCustomer(string Description, string CustomerRef, int ContractTypeId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
        CustomerContracts _newContact = new CustomerContracts();

        try
        {
            _newContact.Description = Description;
            _newContact.CustomerRef = CustomerRef;
            _newContact.ContractTypeId = ContractTypeId;
            _newContact.StartDate = startDate;
            _newContact.EndDate = endDate;
            db.Entry(_newContact).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.CustomerContract.Add(_newContact);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(x.Message) });


        }           

 }
```

When I run the above in post man it gives me an error of the following

> {
>       "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'." }

I have tried the other SO on the same question but its not solving my issue here.

I am using the default route file which is in web api project when its created at first time.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
 }
```

Edit 2

I made the suggestions below and the same result of the error message in postman.

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]


[System.Web.Http.Route("AddCustomer/{Description}/
{CustomerRef}/{ContractTypeId}/{startDate}/{endDate}")]

public async Task AddCustomer(string Description, string CustomerRef, int ContractTypeId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {



        CustomerContracts _newContact = new CustomerContracts();

        try
        {
            _newContact.Description = Description;
            _newContact.CustomerRef = CustomerRef;
            _newContact.ContractTypeId = ContractTypeId;
            _newContact.StartDate = startDate;
            _newContact.EndDate = endDate;
            db.Entry(_newContact).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.CustomerContract.Add(_newContact);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(x.Message) });


        }



    }
```

Comment: *When I run the above in post man* and how are you running this in post man? what URL, etc?

Comment: @Liam via the desktop verison on local host other items get returned ok

Comment: @Liam I edited the question to make that most clear

Answer (score 0):

The `routing attributes` must be exactly the same as how you wrote the `parameters` list names.

So instead of :

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("AddCustomer/{description}/{customerRef}/{contractTypeId}/{startDate}/{EndDate}")]
```

It Should be

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("AddCustomer/{Description}/{CustomerRef}/{ContractTypeId}/{startDate}/{endDate}")]
```

Notice how I changed the path attributes to match the parameters list below.

```
public async Task AddCustomer(string Description, string CustomerRef, int ContractTypeId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{


 }
```

Second: You need to add `WebApiConfig.cs` in `App_Start`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then: In `Global.asax` file in `Application_Start` method, add the following line to register the WebApi Router

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Comment: then how does the default calls work on api/ controller name without that i dont get that

Comment: @DavidB the api/controllername default route is for when you don't add the `[System.Web.Http.Route("AddCustomer/]` attribute over your api functions.

Comment: Do I still need my controller name in that case of just call AddCustomer

Comment: No, you don't need your controller name. the `Route` attribute is totally customizable as long as you maintain unique path patterns

Comment: I am still getting the error message quite strange indeed

Comment: any ideas as this is still hapening